# How to deploy my umbraco site in my own live serve with out umbraco cloud

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm deploying my site to Umbraco Cloud and that's working fine, but I want to deploy to my own live server without Umbraco CLoud services.

I know the process of Umbraco cloud service. 
If I change any content on local Umbraco that can effect on server system without Umbraco as a service, is there any alternate process to do that?

Comment: Yes you can. First you need get database to your local. Then clone umbraco cloud project. Warning: Don't open your website now. You have to change connection string to your local when first time open, if not it will create file and have some problems.
About change content: You need back up and restore your local database to server.

Answer (score 2):

I have not used *Umbraco as a Service* but when hosting sites yourselves there is no standard feature to push content changes from one environment to another.

Umbraco offer A closed-source licensed package *Courier* that is designed to manage the deployment of content:
https://umbraco.com/products-and-support/courier/

Additionally you may wish to investigate uSync.Content. I have used uSync (for document types ect.) with great success but have not used the Content edition: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/usynccontentedition/

The final, more hands on, approach is to do a database compare between environments to generate update scripts that can be applied but this does require a good understanding of the Umbraco schema to avoid overwriting/loosing content.

Comment: what about a web deploy through visual studio if you downloaded Umbraco as a nugget package?

Comment: @blackhawk yes you can deploy the source code to your own server absolutely via Web publish but it would not include any content changes that would be otherwise handled by UaaS

Comment: what about exporting packages of content and importing then into another environment.  any side effects with that?  thanks

Comment: @blackhawk I have not used the packages extensively so couldn't say for sure but I am sure it would work for simple doc types just fine. I do not believe it would handle related content too well as primary keys would be out of sync between the sites